# Joomla! 3 how to remove hyperlink from notification when a new article has been posted

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.2, joomla3.4

I want to remove the hyperlink from notification mail when a new article has been posted. I just need the message not the link. Is there any way to edit the notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All message is defined in the language file. You can find your here:

> .../language/en-GB/en-GB.com_content.ini

Comment: I am new to this . For example this is the message i am getting
"Please log in to http://www.example.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_messages&view=message&message_id=7 to read your message."... I dont want the link to be appear on the mail. please help me

Comment: open in your server FTP folder `/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_messages.ini` and erase the `%s` in `COM_MESSAGES_PLEASE_LOGIN="Please log in to %s to read your message."`

Comment: I have removed it ..but still am getting the mail with hyperlink when a new article is published

Comment: Why you unsolved this? You ask want remove link on "please login in to url to read your message", this is the message you receve when you receve a private message in joomla admin but no when a article is published. For this please see my answer. Look your mail text and find it on `en-GB.com_content.ini` and change this.

Comment: I think there is a confusion. When an article published the editor will get a message like A new private message has arrived from example.com Please log in to http://example.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_messages&view=message&message_id=5 to read your message. If we click the link it wil re direct to the backend. so that the editors can access the backend..I want to stop this. Is there any way to send the notification as text without hyperlink @P. Frank

Comment: Ok. Its right. If you remove the %s normaly you receive mail without link.  Please clean all joomla cache and retry.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use the language overrides which can be access through the administrative tools instead.

This way, you won't make core modifications that will be lost in future updates.

Go to "Extensions -> Language(s)" and go to the "Overrides" section.

The interface allows to look for variable names or content and will save the language overrides in a different INI file without overriding the core language files.